# Converting pages created by MVC project to HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a designer that creates a site using Visual Stuido. He says it is easier for him: templates and all.

The result of the project are 3 simple HTML pages that have to be put on the server with their images, scripts and stylesheets.

Right now I have to take every page, save its source as shown by the browser, save all assets (images, JS and CSS). Then I have to make sure that links to those assets are correct before I upload everything to the server. It is a lot of manual work with high chance of error.

I really don't want to create a separate application instance for that. It is another application in the cloud to be maintained just for 3 HTML pages.

Is there an easy way to render HTML from MVC project?

Comment: Why not just take the site as published from Visual Studio and put it on your web server as is?

Comment: I have no servers. Everything is in the cloud. I just don't have Windows server for this project. And it seems, getting whole IIS for 3 static HTML pages is plainly stupid.